# Set the background of UILabel to transparent black

Tags: ios, swift, swift3, storyboard, uilabel

I have a UILabel that whose background I want to set to black with alpha component so that this label can have a transparent black background.

In the storyboard when I set the background to the colour I want with an alpha component even the text of the label that is in white colour becomes lighter with the alpha component.

To overcome this problem I embedded the label in a UIView and even then the same problem persists.

How can I overcome this problem. Any help will be appreciated.

Comment: myLabel.backgroundColor = UIColor.black.withAlphaComponent(0)

Comment: Don't set alpha form Storyboard set Label's color and alpha using coding. This will not apply to text of the label.
lbl.backgroundColor = [UIColor colorWithRed:100/225.0 green:100.0/255.0 blue:100.0/255.0 alpha:.7];

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can Do only With label make IBObject an write following line.

```
label.backgroundColor = UIColor.black.withAlphaComponent(0.4)
```

Answer (score 5):

Instead of changing the alpha value, change the opacity of the label background color in storyboard.

For better understanding, I have taken an imageView and placed a label at the bottom of imageView and changed the background color of the label and textColor to white. At this stage you can't see the image behind the label.

[image]

Now, go to attributes inspector and select the label background color. There you can see the opacity and change it's value. Here I have made it 50%, you can change it to whatever you want between 0 to 100 until you get your desired transparency.

[image]

Comment: @KishoreKumar Yes, it is easy and effective way to make your view transparent without affecting the subviews. But I don't think it is possible through code...

Answer (score 3):

create the UIview with black background color and add the UIlabel inside the view and set the alpha to **0.5** of view . finally you get the black transparent, for e.g

[image]

**if you need the label text in bold change the view hierarchy**

> place the UILabel fist then add the UIView.

Answer (score 0):

Place the `UILabel`above the `UIView`, not inside it.

Answer (score 0):

Assume that we are talking about `v1` the view that contains your `label` , if `v1` is **over** another view that has **bright colors** then when your `v1`'s `alpha` get lower your label white text color will become harder to see , the text color has nothing to do with the background alpha component , so you need to reconsider using the white color or the `alpha component` background or the view that is behind v1 make it darker that's all we can say